# Can't build android project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm using react-native. my project was working well but after few months i have to add some changes to my project. now that i'm trying to build project using `react-native run-android` it throws an exception.

i searched for problem and all solution says edit build.gradle and add `google()` before each repository, none of them worked for me.

the exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.2.1/tracker-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.2.1/shared-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.2.1/crash-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.2.1/lint-gradle-api-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.2.1/gradle-api-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.2.1/databinding-compiler-common-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.2.1/manifest-merger-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.2.1/sdk-common-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.2.1/builder-test-api-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.2.1/ddmlib-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.2.1/sdklib-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.2.1/layoutlib-api-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.2.1/dvlib-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.2.1/repository-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.2.1/common-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-alpha10).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-alpha10.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.5.0/bundletool-0.5.0.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-alpha10).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-alpha10/jetifier-core-1.0.0-alpha10.jar
   > Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.2.1/builder-model-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.2.1/protos-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.2.1/apkzlib-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.2.1/apksig-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.2.1/annotations-26.2.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.2.1/databinding-common-3.2.1.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.1/baseLibrary-3.2.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (F:\clone\Remote_Device_Controller\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (F:\clone\Remote_Device_Controller\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (F:\clone\Remote_Device_Controller\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

build.gradle repositories:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

anyone has an idea what happened to my project when i didn't even touch 1 line from the last time i built my project successfully?

BTW it's so weird that the link which says could not be found is working well, i copied and pasted that in my browser. it could download that manually

Comment: You should first navigate from you project directory to android folder and run command for clean project from command line: **./gradlew clean**. and navigate back to project folder and try to run again.  Also try to increase version of gradle wrapper, which you can find in gradle folder -> gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: @mmmatey same error when trying to gradlew clean

Comment: Did you changed the version of Android Studio or gradle in the meantime? Anyway, you may want to try with "invalidate caches and restart". Also, sometimes closing project, removing it from AS's list of projects and importing again helps with solving strange issues.

Comment: @Amas try to change 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:' version to newest one for example to version 3.3.1, also set your targetSdkVersion = 28, not 27.